# How to use Concurrent Collections .NET - Am I doing it right?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, multithreading

I have a list of strings,`gObject.RotationItems` I want to be able to rotate through those list of strings in a thread-safe way and start over when I reach the end.  I have a dictionary object retain the order for each key, whether it's `Rotation1` as seen below, or some other keys, as there will be different keys.

I'm using `SyncLock` to make sure threads to step on each other for a true rotation. But, do I really need to use SyncLock? Since I'm using a thread-safe collection? Does it need to be coded a little differently, if I remove the SyncLock? To ensure I rotate through the list of strings uniquely, over and over.

Look over my code, I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it, or if someone can offer a suggestion or improvement.

The code is in vb.net, but a c# suggestion will work as well.

```
NotInheritable Class gObject
  Public Shared RotationItems As New List(Of String)
  Public Shared Rotation As New Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary(Of String, Integer)
End Class


  SyncLock gObject.BindObject

        Dim iRotationOrder As Integer = 0
        If gObject.Rotation.TryGetValue("Rotation1", iRotationOrder ) Then
            If iRotationOrder >= gObject.RotationItems.Count - 1 Then
                gObject.Rotation.TryUpdate("Rotation1", 0, iRotationOrder )
            Else
                gObject.Rotation.TryUpdate("Rotation1", iRotationOrder + 1, iRotationOrder )
            End If
        Else
            iRotationOrder = 0
            gObject.Rotation.TryAdd("Rotation1", 0)
        End If

        Return gObject.RotationItems(iRotationOrder)
    End SyncLock
```

Comment: What are you using this for?

Comment: I'm keeping track of different items (keys)["rotation1", "rotation2", "rotation3"] and where they are at in the rotation based on usage. If I wasn't keeping track of multiple items, I can probably do this in a concurrentqueue. Dequeue then Enqueue it back. "Rotation1" is actually a random string being passed in, and the dictionary keeps track of it. I simplified it for this example.

Comment: The point of `ConcurrentDictionary` is that reads and writes will never be interleaved, i.e. if you're doing one read/write on one thread then another read/write on another thread will not occur while the first one is partially complete.  If that's all you're concerned about, you don't need to use `SyncLock`.  If you want to perform multiple reads/writes as an atomic action then you will still need `SyncLock`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney The above happens once per thread, envision lets say 2000 threads at once. Will the above code ever  duplicate, or skip an `RotationItems`,if their was 2000 strings in the 'rotationsItems" list? Without the `Synclock`

Comment: Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary has build-in locking logic - you should drop all lock logic in your code and it will work good. It is probably will be more effective - as it might use `ReaderWriterLockSlim` inside - even if it not - that is possible in the future releases.